What does my gcc-compiled program depend on?
I'm trying to understand the dependencies of a C program, and I'm slowly realizing that gcc main.c -o main is hiding a lot of details.
Here's my experiment (ubuntu-wsl-x64):

As you can see, my program is linked to

The GNU libc (through a symbolic link libc.so.6)
The GNU linker (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
A weird dynamic library (linux-vdso.so.1)

To my understanding, the linux-vdso.so.1 will implement certain libc  API to improve the speed of certain system calls.
Questions:

Why is linux-vdso.so.1 is not already included in libc?
Why is ld dynamically linked to my executable? Is it used at runtime?
To my understanding, my program also should depend on libgcc and crt0 are they linked statically?
There must be a -I hidden so the program can see the libc header file. Am I correct? I so, where are they?
Am I missing something else?

Thanks, kind strangers.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

"Is it used at runtime?" I think that's part of the dynamic linking mechanism.

Hi barmar, I'll keep that in mind. That said, in this case, the bullet list summarizes the image.

"I think that's part of the dynamic linking mechanism". Sure, but if it's part of the toolchain steps, why link it to the executable?

Including it in text form still saves us, the answers, time if we want to reproduce and experiment to get our answer polished up nice and shiny. As it is, we have to re-type your text. Granted, it's not much to type, but it's still extra work for potentially multiple other helpful people that you could have saved with just a bit of extra effort.

This ld is the LoaDer of executable file, but not the linker

Sure, but if it's part of the toolchain steps, why link it to the executable? - dynamic linking is happening in run-time. Hence "dynamic".

@StasSimonov Not accurate: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux

@EugeneSh I want to escape confusion.

The answer to your question #5 is "yes - several books' worth." Start with Linkers and Loaders (John Levine) and The Standard C Library (P.J. Plauger). Both books are a little dated but correct in their essentials and well written.

Add the -v option when you do the compilation.  It will report what commands are executed and their arguments.  There's a lot happening behind the scenes.

Please edit your question to ask one thing; questions on Stack Overflow must ask one question, not multiple.

@zwol ""yes - several books' worth" hehe you're absolutely right ! I'll get there someday. Thanks for the recommendation.

@TylerH This is one question: what is gcc hiding? I decomposed my question in subquestion to help the audience  understand what I mean. If that make sense.

@JonathanLeffler good idea. Thanks !

@gberth I understand that is one question. I still see 5 different questions in your actual post.


As you can see, my program is linked to

The GNU libc (through a symbolic link libc.so.6)


Yes.


The GNU linker (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)


No.  That is not the GNU linker (ld).  It is the Linux dynamic linker.  It serves as the standard ELF program loader on Linux.  Every ELF executable needs such a loader in order to run.


A weird dynamic library (linux-vdso.so.1)


Sort of.  "vdso" is an initialism of "virtual dynamic shared object".  This particular one is provided to every process by the Linux kernel, and the C standard library relies on it for various kernel services.  It is not bundled into libc because for all intents and purposes, it is part of the kernel.


To my understanding, my program also should depend on libgcc and crt0 are they linked statically?


Some programs compiled with GCC depend on libgcc.  Others don't.  It depends on the program.  libgcc could be linked statically -- GCC has a command-line option for that -- but if you didn't ask for that then it probably isn't.
I don't know what crt0 is, maybe this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0? As far as I know, that does not take the form of a separate shared library, so ldd would not tell you about it.

There must be a -I hidden so the program can see the libc header file. Am I correct? I so, where are they?

No, you are not correct.  GCC has a default search path for include files that includes the headers for the standard library with which it is integrated.  You use a -I option to add directories to that search path, but you don't need one for the standard library headers, or for others installed in that path (and what a pain it would be if you did!).  Gcc will tell you what the default search path is if you ask it.


Am I missing something else?


Probably many things, given the nature of the specific questions posed.  It's hard to say which of them may actually be of interest to you in this context, and likely impossible to fit them into the scope of an SO answer.

You can use the -v option to gcc to see the (default) search path for include files (the "hidden" -I options), along with many other things.

This is very helpful. I recognize that my question is open ended.
This kind of knowledge is hard to acquire, in my experience. So thank you so much for taking the time.
